# WX.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK click for different video

Tags: python, video, hyperlink, listbox, wxpython

I have a problem when I do click on the listbox, In my program, I did click on the listbox will appear a video. I made a sample in the database are "name_link" which will appear in the listbox. Video1, Video2, Video3. Of each name_link have different video. However, that happens every time I click on one of these name_link, video that appears only Video3. When I click name_link video1 video2 emerging or always Video3. I am so stuck in this section.

This section during click:

```
self.opt = wx.ListBox(pan1, -1, pos=(10, 210), size=(480, 250), style= wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)

def playFile(self, event):
    self.player.Play()

def OnEnter(self, event):
    self.opt.SetLabel(self.PatMatch()) 

def PatMatch(self):
    con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')    
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        for row in cur.execute("Select * From Video"):
            klmt = self.inpt.GetValue()
            if row[1] in klmt.lower():  
                self.opt.Append(row[2])         
               self.player.Load(row[4])
        return self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK, self.playFile, self.op)
```

The database like this :

```
id  word        name_link   explain     link
--- ------      ----------- ---------   --------
1   python      Video1      test        C:\Users\Ihsan\Downloads\Video1.MP4
2   python      Video2      test1       C:\Users\Ihsan\Downloads\Video2.MP4
3   python      Video3      test2       C:\Users\Ihsan\Downloads\Video3.MP4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ClientData` for the item in the list. Check the following quick code. By using `ClientData` you can display different labels for items and store the necessary data for each item.

```
import wx

db = [
          {"id": 1, "name_link": "Video 1", "link": "C:\\first_video.mp4"},
          {"id": 2, "name_link": "Video 2", "link": "C:\\second_video.mp4"},
          {"id": 3, "name_link": "Video 3", "link": "C:\\third_video.mp4"},
      ]

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="List of Videos")

        self.opt = wx.ListBox(self)
        self.fillOpt()

        self.opt.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK, self.startVideo)
        self.Show()

    def fillOpt(self):
        for row in db:
            self.opt.Append(row['name_link'], row['link']) # Label, ClientData

    def startVideo(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox(parent=self, message=event.GetClientData(), caption="Video")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Mr. @arvinchhi ur code is work. now i want to try output value from column explain and video. For video is show in "self.player = wx.media.MediaCtrl(pan2, pos=(80, 55), size=(800, 600), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)" and for value from column explain can show in "self.pjs = wx.TextCtrl(pan1, -1, pos=(10, 440), size=(480, 230), style= wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)". when i give condition "self.opt.Append(row[2], row[3], row[4]), its doesn't work. can u help me ?

Comment: `self.opt` is a `ListBox`. The method `Append` takes atleast one and atmost two arguments: `Append(String item, PyObject clientData)`. You are trying to provide three arguments thats why it wont work.

Comment: You should provide `clientData` as a `dict` or `list` or `tuple`. And access the values using keys or index. For example: `self.opt.Append(row[2], [row[3], row[4]])`

Comment: its still not work, i put in "self.opt.Append(row[2], [row[3], row[4]])" in my code. Video and value from sentence not show.

Comment: Mr. @arvinchhi please, can u give me a example how to create clientdata as a dict or list or tuple in my code. coz, i never use that before.

Comment: Use `self.opt.Append(row[2], [row[3], row[4]])` as I suggested in my previous comment. Now, do following: **#1**: get your clientdata in a variable (`data = event.GetClientData()`). **#2**: get _explain_ like this `explain = data[0]`. **#3**: get _link_ like this `link = data[1]`

Comment: <pre>
i create code like this, its right or not.

def playVideo(self, event):
  data = event.GetClientData()
  explain = data[0]
  link = data[1]
  
  self.player.Load(data.link)
  self.Play(True)
  self.pjs.Clear()
  self.pjs.Append(data.explain)
</pre>

Comment: Mr. @arvinchhi my code now is work, Thank you very much for ur help.